# Restrict installing applications on Android mobile

Tags: android

I'm creating an application for a client who only wants their customers to run only this certain application. Also they are going to provide the mobile phone with the application per-installed. Client does not want their customers to install other apps from play-store or from APK files.

Is there any way to achieve this task through Android stock OS?

Comment: I guess you are looking for a COSU device (Corporate Owned, Single Use) then here's the guidelines - https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html

Comment: create your own launcher.

Comment: Creating a launcher might be the fastest way, but still you can access device Settings, and thus install new apps, and install a new launcher which nullify the entire purpose of our app. In COSU mode, the developer will have full control over the device — including visibility of navigation bar, status bar, screen lock, and even starts our app upon the device booting.

Comment: Thank you all. I'll try COSU and the launcher and choose what is better for the app.